# How to retrive the results saved in model of gensim?

Tags: text-mining, word-embeddings, gensim, word2vec

I have a file that contains words. I have to calculate cosine similarity of each word with every other words. For that I used the following formula in gensim:

- model.most_similar([word])
- model.save('text.txt')

I want to save the result of cosine-similarity of each words with respective to other words in such a way that I can used them further in classification and clustering. But don't know how to retrieve the results which are saved using gensim model ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not really clear.

If the question is how can you save and retrieve the cosine-similarity of each word with every other word, then you can save them in an array and use [pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) for saving and loading them again.

Or, If the question is how you can retrieve the `gensim model`, then the function is `gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load()`